# Why input type='file' does not dispatch Event?

Tags: javascript, html, events, event-handling, dom-events

**Why this simple example does not work?:**

```html
<input id="image" type="file"/>
<img src='https://cdn.elegantthemes.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/custom-trackable-short-url-feature.png' onclick='imageLoad()'></img>
<script>
  function imageLoad() {    
    let ev = new Event('click', {bubbles: true});
    image.dispatchEvent(ev); 
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Define "it doesn't work". `image` is undefined, your console is probably telling you this

Comment: Also note that `img` is a [*void element*](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#void-elements), it never has a closing tag. You never write `</img>`. In HTML, it's just `<img src="...">`. In XHTML (which you probably aren't using), it's `<img src="..." />`.

Comment: @JeremyThille: Sadly, `image` isn't undefined, it's an automatic global for the file input, because it has an `id`. :-|

Comment: @T.J. No way O_o

Comment: @JeremyThille: Sadly: https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/browsers.html#named-access-on-the-window-object :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, check the `<img>` close tag.
Second, you can't dispatch the click event of the input through js since the secure principle of the browser.
For div, it will be ok:

```js
function imageLoad() { 
    let image = document.querySelector('#div');
    let ev = new Event('click', {bubbles: true});
    image.dispatchEvent(ev); 
  }
  
function clickDiv(){
  console.log('clicked the div');
}
```

```html
<input id="image" type="file" />
<div id="div" onclick="clickDiv()">123</div>
<img src='https://cdn.elegantthemes.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/custom-trackable-short-url-feature.png' onclick='imageLoad()' />
```

Answer (score 3):

It is correct that certain security implications apply but depending on your goal it will work in this example if you change the `Event` constructor to a `MouseEvent`.

```
...
<body>
<input id="image" type="file" />
<img id="handle" src="https://cdn.elegantthemes.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/custom-trackable-short-url-feature.png" />
<script>
  let handle = document.getElementById('handle');
  handle.addEventListener('click', imageLoad, false);

  function imageLoad() {
    let ev = new MouseEvent('click', {bubbles: true});
    image.dispatchEvent(ev); 
  }
</script>
...
```

Comment: This is a great answer and it works. Interesting fact: Safari on iOS will dispatch the event without the need of this trick, even with all the security implications.

Answer (score 1):

Just repeating `Peter Pajchl`, for those in the back:

```html
<!-- an ugly file input (quick, hide it away!) -->
<input
    type="file"
    id="htmlFileInputElement"
    style="position: absolute; top: -1000px; left: -1000px;"
/>


<!-- a beautiful, inviting button -->
<button onclick="
    htmlFileInputElement.dispatchEvent(
        new MouseEvent('click', { bubbles: true })
    )
">Upload File</button>
```

(since this page is the number one search hit for styling a file input and all)